# Visual Studio Test Controller 2013 name

Tags: visual-studio-2013, distributed, load-testing

I am unable to find the Test Controller name for distributed load testing in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, how would I go about finding the name?

Answer (score 2):

Try the IP address with 6901 (e.g. 127.0.0.1:6901)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else curious about this issue, after running the Test Agent Configuration wizard successfully run you can see a more detailed log. The name will be listed on the 9th line as

I, date, time, Getting information about controller: Controller Name.